# Can I see a list of questions that I have favourited?

Tags: support, android-app, bookmarks, favorites-notifications, favorites-tab

I have been favouring questions using my phone for a few weeks thinking that I would look at them later, but I don't think there is any way I can see questions that I  favourite. Or is there?

If it is not possible, then what is the point of marking a question as a favourite?

If you can see them, than how? I am using my android phone.

Comment: App or web browser?

Comment: I am using android app.

Answer (score 4):

Your original question didn't specify whether you're using the desktop site, mobile site, or mobile app, so here are the directions for the desktop site:

> ... any way I can see questions that I favourite.

- Favorites for [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites)
- Favorites for one specific site: [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites)

Go to your "Activity" tab in your [user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current), and click on the "Favorites" tab:

[image: User Profile]

Comment: The author has since commented that they're using the app.

Comment: That are some very very nice [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775). What is your secret? Zoom in in Paint and draw?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't know what the author used, but the Photos app on Windows 10 produces similar circles.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - The Galaxy S9+ has a screenshot feature that can do a few things before actually saving, one of them is draw. So the workflow is: screenshot, crop, pen, choose pen style and color, zoom in, draw, save. There are some [fancy pen/pencil/felt/brush styles, widths, infinite colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZVJM.png) available.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Screenshot technique explained, with a screenshot of the screenshot screenshot. PS: Thanks for the edit.